# Characteristic function of a sum of Uniform random variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

Suppose I have $S=U_1+U_2+\dots+U_n$ where $U_i$ are distributed Uniform$[-1,1]$.

I am trying to show a couple of things. First, what is the characteristic function. I can show this easily enough for a single uniform RV, but for some reason the sum is not coming to me.

Second, does the inversion formula apply as long as $n\ge2$? and if so, how can I show this?

Finally, how can I use the inversion formula to show a real-valued integral for the density (i.e getting rid of the imaginary part of the characteristic function)?

I have worked through how to derive a single $U$, but these extensions escape me.

Many thanks for the help~

Comment: Are your $U_j$ independent?  One of the most important properties of characteristic functions is about the characteristic function of the sum of independent random variables.

Comment: yes they are iid....and I believe that means that I can take the product of their individual characteristic functions, correct? I'm still somewhat fuzzy on the second and third parts though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The characteristic function is an expectation:
$$
    \varphi_S(t) = \mathbb{E}\left(\exp(i S t)\right) = \mathbb{E}\left(\exp\left(i \left(U_1 + U_2 + \cdots + U_n \right) t\right)\right)
$$
Now, if $U_i$ is *independent*, the expectation factors into product of expectations, because :
$$
    \varphi_S(t) = \mathbb{E}\left(\mathrm{e}^{i t U_1}\cdot \mathrm{e}^{i t U_2} \cdots \mathrm{e}^{i t U_n}\right) = \mathbb{E}\left(\mathrm{e}^{i t U_1} \right)\cdot  \mathbb{E}\left(\mathrm{e}^{i t U_2} \right) \cdots  \mathbb{E}\left(\mathrm{e}^{i t U_n}\right)
$$
Since $U_i$ have identical distributions, these expectations are the same, thus:
$$
   \varphi_S(t) = \left(\mathbb{E}\left(\mathrm{e}^{i t U} \right)\right)^n = \left( \frac{\sin(t)}{t}\right)^n
$$

According to the [inversion formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_%28probability_theory%29#Inversion_formulas), there is one-to-one correspondence between cumulative distribution function, and the characteristic function. Since $\varphi_S(t)$ is a characteristic function for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ by construction, the inversion formula applies for all natural $n$.

Moverover, if $\varphi_S(t)$ is *integrable*, then $F_S(x)$ is absolutely continuous, i.e. the notion of the probability density function is well-defined. Notice that $\varphi_S(t)$ is absolutely integrable for $n \geqslant 2$, by virtue of $|\varphi_S(t)| \leqslant \min\left(1, t^{-n}\right)$, and hence integrable. However, $\varphi_S(t)$ is also conditionally integrable for $n=1$ (the integral is known as [Dirichlet integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_integral)).

Applying the inversion formula to obtain an explicit expression for the probability density is somewhat involved. This [earlier post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146741/using-contour-integration-or-other-means-is-there-a-way-to-find-a-general-form/146764#146764) of mine contains the derivation.

To conclude, let me remark, that the sum of iid uniform continuous random variable follows what is known as the [Irwin-Hall distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution).

Comment: Looks like for Irwin-Hall the U$_i$ are all U[0,1] and not U[-1,1].

Comment: Yes, but the rescaling is trivial.

Comment: @Sasha, thank you for the help! Speaking in general, if I want to derive the moments of a distribution using its characteristic function, do I just take the "nth" derivative with respect to the parameter and evaluate at t=0? If so, how does this apply to a distribution with multiple parameters (such as Gamma($\alpha,\Beta$)?

Comment: @Sasha Okay but be careful with your terminology.