# Recurrence for $\int \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^n \, \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I was playing around and wanted to consider the integral of $$I_n = \int_0^{\infty} \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^n \, \mathrm{d}x$$ using parts with $u = \sin^n x \implies \mathrm{d}u = n\cos x \sin^{n-1}x$ and $\mathrm{d}v = x^{-n} \implies v = \frac{x^{1-n}}{1-n}$

This gives $$I_n = \frac{n}{n-1}\int_0^{\infty} \left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^{n-1} \cos x \, \mathrm{d}x$$

Which looks so close to $I_{n-1}$ but for that annoying $\cos x$ there, any help?

Note: I wanted to go down this route because I think I can note a pattern, as such: 
$$I_1 = \frac{\pi}{2} \\ I_2 = \frac{\pi}{2} \\ I_3 = \frac{3\pi}{8} \\ I_4 = \frac{\pi}{3} \\ I_5 = \frac{115\pi}{384} \\ I_6 = \frac{11\pi}{40}$$

Comment: try to use the integration by parts once again

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky With $u = \sin^{n-1}x \cos x$ and $\mathrm{d}v = x^{1-n}$?

Comment: no, leave the cosinus for du to get $\cos^2x=1-\sin^2x$

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky so $u = \sin^{n-1} x$ and $\mathrm{d}v = \frac{\cos x}{x^{n-1}}$?

Comment: another integration by parts didn't work for me yet, also expected it would

Comment: It seems that one has to deal with the more general integral 

$$I_{m, n} = \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin^m x}{x^n} dx,\ \ \  \text{where } m\ge n.$$

By using integration by part twice, one obtains

$$I_{m, n}= \frac{m(m-1)}{(n-1)(n-2)} I_{m-2, n-2} - \frac{m^2}{(n-1)(n-2)} I_{m,n-2}.$$

Comment: But I am still working on the base case: $I_{m, 1}$ and $I_{m,2}$.

Comment: It might be a good idea (I did not test it completely) to use Fourier transforms and convolutions.

Comment: @JohnMa what advantage does working out the more general integral bring? :)

Comment: @mickep - I know what those are, but they are a tad too advanced a technique for me to use. ;-)

Comment: @ZainPatel Because after integration by part twice one has that term $I_{m,n-2}$ unfortunately.

Comment: @JohnMa - ah, okay, yeah, that makes sense!

Comment: @MichaelMedvinsky. I deleted my answer. Thanks for the link. But the summation disappears because using Eulerian numbers which are given explicitly bya sum ! Cheers

Comment: @Claude Leibovici sure!   I will just put the link here so it available http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SincFunction.html

Comment: See here:   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146741/using-contour-integration-or-other-means-is-there-a-way-to-find-a-general-form